# Sum over pairs of nodes forming a triangle

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, symmetric-matrices, network, adjacency-matrix

Given a simple graph $G=(V, E)$ and a matrix, $C$, describing a property for each pair of nodes, e.g., the adjacency matrix, or the matrix describing the number of common triangles of two nodes. Is it possible to describe the vector 
$$\mathbf{x} = \Big(\sum_{x \sim y, \, x\sim z, \, y \sim z} C_{y,z} \text{ for } x \in V\Big)$$
in terms of matrix equations using the adjacency matrix?

I know, for example, that the number of shared triangles between each pair of nodes can be described as $A^2 \odot A$. Hence, if the matrix $C = (c)_{i,j\in V}$ is constant, the above vector can be expressed as 
$$\mathbf{x} = \frac{c}{2}(A^2 \odot A) \mathbf{1} \, .$$
However, I fail to see if this can be generalized to an arbitrary symmetric matrix $C$.

---

**Edit**: It has been mentioned that if $C$ is a constant, $\mathbf{x}$ can also be expressed via the diagonal of $A^3$, i.e.
$$\mathbf{x} = c \cdot\operatorname{diag}\big(A^3\big) \, .$$

Comment: Maybe I am confusing something.. If $C$ is constant, shouldn't the vector be the diagonal of $cA^3$? The sum defining the vector $\bf x$ has $x$ fixed?

Comment: No, you are right. It can also be expressed as the diagonal of $A^3$. And yes, $x$ in the sum is fixed and denotes the "coordinate" of the vector.

Comment: ok. Then there's an easy way to generalize

Comment: Wouldn't call it easy... you are my hero right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\sum_{x \sim y, \, x\sim z, \, y \sim z} C_{y,z}
=
\sum_{y,z} A_{x,y} A_{y,z}C_{y,z}A_{z,x} 
=
(A(A\odot C)A)_{x,x}
$$
so
$$
\mathbf{x} = diag(A(A\odot C)A ) = ((A(A\odot C)) \odot A) \mathbf{1}
$$